# Show alert icon in the field in Odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I wanted to show an alert icon in ***partner_id***(Customer) field if the Tax ID of *partner_id* is empty. This icon should be similar to the icon we see in **Invoice Date** if a future date is given.

[image]

Conditions when  icon should be shown

- if *partner_id*'s type is *individual* and has *parent_id*(**Company**) then **Tax ID** should be chosen from parent_id not from parntner_id. So, if the Tax ID of parent_id is empty, the alert icon should be shown.
- if partner_id is individual and has no parent_id(company) then Tax ID should be chosen from partner_id. And if it is empty, an alert icon should be shown.
- if partner_id is company type and has no Tax ID, an icon should be shown.

***How can I achieve such feature?***

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onchange method, if you change the partner the icon is displayed
but if you want like the date icon it's a bit long because it's a widget

good for the method it's like this

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice' 

    @api.onchange('partner_id')
    def tax_check(self):  
        if self.partner_id.parent_id and self.partner_id.company_type == 'person':
            if not self.partner_id.parent_id.vat :
              #  display your icon
            else:
               # chose the tax for parent_id
        elif not self.partner_id.parent_id and self.partner_id.company_type == 'person':
            if self.partner_id.vat :
                # chose the tax in partner_id
            else:
                #  afficher votre icone 
        elif not self.partner_id.vat and self.partner_id.company_type == 'company':
            #  display your icon
```

you want to display the TaxID in the report ?

Comment: Original account.invoice has its own @api.onchange('partner_id'), won't this code affect the original one. How can two @api.onchange("partner_id") work? and this code can help to raise an error but how to display that icon which I wanted?

Comment: you can inherit the same method  [@api.onchange('partner_id')
    def _onchange_partner_id(self):] and add your condition, but it's normal several onchange on the same field, to display the icon you can add a boolean field for example true / false, if false he icon is displayed!

Comment: How should I put an icon inside that partner_id field? I tried variously but all in vain.

Comment: if you talk to the icon like the date, it's a widget, here it is
https://i.ibb.co/4mGDCxd/Screenshot-20200220-101954.png

Comment: in options what is _datepicker_ and _warn_future_, what should I write in my xml code?

Comment: [datepicker] it's a widget for the date field type in odoo you can't help in your case

Comment: but you wrote to display your icon, How can I do that?

Comment: this is an example, you can change by displaying a boolean true/false field
if false you can display an exception or raise like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0i6C.png